# Twitter Tweetable Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, twitter

I have a site which used to use the [seaofclouds](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) Jquery Plugin for twitter. Ever since twitter changed the API the plugin stopped working.

I have found a solution by using a [new plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/tweetable/) which I downloaded from Github. The only issue is since there is a minor lag in the plugin fetching the tweets from the API.

I want to display the message: "Loading Tweets" whilst the tweets are loading and until they are loaded.

This is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#tweets').tweetable({
            username: 'myusername',
            time: true,
            limit: 3,   
            replies: false,
            position: 'append',
            failed: "Sorry, twitter is currently unavailable for this user.",
            html5: true,
            onComplete:function($ul) {
                $('time').timeago();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I still think the below answer is a good answer - you know I went into the source code of your library for you to see exactly if it was possible?

Comment: YEs it is. But i have realised now that this JS cant work with the new API. nowr can i use the PHP Oauth solution since im running dotnetnuke. So im just gonna stick with the Twitter widget :-)

Comment: I mean it works fine in some regions and then it does not in other.. Same-origin issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/philipbeel/Tweetable/wiki#plugin-parameters) for your chosen library, it looks like that `onComplete` is the only callback you can use.

Short of going into the source code and modifying it yourself, you have another option.

It looks like that calling `.tweetable()` messes with your current `<div>`s html. So, you want to perform the following:

- Hide your `$('#tweets')` element right at the start - set it's style to `display: none;`
- Have another `div` containing "Loading..." that is visible
- In the complete method, hide your loading `<div>` and show `$('#tweets')` instead

**HTML**

```
<div id="tweets" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

**jQuery (in your complete function)**

```
onComplete:function($ul) {
    $('time').timeago();
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#tweets').fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
```

Of course, I used `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` here, but you could easily use `hide()` and `show()` instead.